# Incorrect CSS alignment (left margin) of the "questions with new activity" bar

Tags: bug, design

So I noticed a little CSS bug in the

> N questions with new activity

bar, which has an extra left margin that should not be there:

[image: screenshot with bug]

It can be fixed by simply removing a single CSS rule:

[image: site with edited CSS]

You should delete the following rule from `stacks.css`, or alter it so that it does not match here, in case it's needed somewhere else.

```
.ml8 {
    margin-left: 8px !important;
}
```

Comment: I just noticed that this might be due to the change to the new global style, like here on MSE, where those 8px of left margin fit the layout. So probably some of the new style rules sneaked into the sites which still have the old style?